# Pandas: how to turn time-series rows into a contiguous set of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table that stores the steps by that an item is transferred (purposely made in Python Pandas for ease of reproduction):

```sql
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([
(1, 1, '2023-01-01 00:00:00', 'Arrive in Warehouse', 'PS5'),
(2, 1, '2023-02-01 00:00:00', 'Packaging', 'PS5'),
(3, 1, '2023-03-01 00:00:00':, 'Shipping', 'PS5'),
(4, 1, '2023-04-01 00:00:00', 'Received', 'PS5'),
(5, 2, '2023-01-01 00:00:00', 'Arrive in Warehouse', 'Fan'),
(6, 2, '2023-01-02 00:00:00', 'Checking failures', 'Fan'),
(7, 2, '2023-01-03 00:00:00', 'Shipping', 'Fan'),
(8, 2, '2023-01-04 00:00:00', 'Received', 'Fan')
], columns = ['PK', 'ID', 'DATE', 'STATUS', 'NAME'])
```

I want to do something like PIVOT for the column `STATUS` that "breaks" it into multiple columns and inserts the corresponding `DATE` as the value. Expected output:

| ID | Arrive in Warehouse | Checking failures | Packaging | Shipping | Received | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 |  | 2023-02-01 | 2023-03-01 | 2023-04-01 | PS5 |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-02 |  | 2023-01-03 | 2023-01-04 | Fan |

Some assumptions and requirements that I have to follow:

- The table is already sorted by `ID, NAME`. The `STATUS` is also sorted in the correct flow for each `ID`.
- The name and flow of `STATUS` is known beforehand in a separate dataframe, it looks like `(1, 'Arrive in Warehouse'), (2, 'Checking failures'), (3, 'Packaging'),...`, if that helps
- The "pivot" process should not change the order of the columns, and should be able to generalize to an arbitrary number of columns after `STATUS`. As you see in the example,   `Name` is the last column in the table, and it should also be the last column in the "pivoted" table. In my actual table, there are 3 columns before the `DATE` column and a lot of them after the `STATUS` column.
- Each combination of `ID-DATE-STATUS` appears only once in the table, so no need to de-duplicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with key parameter in [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with helper function by mapping columns names by dictionary:

```
L = [(1, 'Arrive in Warehouse'), (2, 'Checking failures'),
     (3, 'Packaging'), (4, 'Shipping'), (5, 'Received')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','b'])

d = df1.set_index('b')['a'].to_dict()

df = (df.pivot(index=['ID', 'NAME'], columns='STATUS', values='DATE')
        .sort_index(axis=1, key=lambda x: x.map(d))
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
        .assign(NAME = lambda x: x.pop('NAME')))
print (df)
   ID  Arrive in Warehouse    Checking failures            Packaging  \
0   1  2023-01-01 00:00:00                  NaN  2023-02-01 00:00:00   
1   2  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00                  NaN   

              Shipping             Received NAME  
0  2023-03-01 00:00:00  2023-04-01 00:00:00  PS5  
1  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00  Fan
```

Another idea is use ordered [`categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/categorical.html):

```
L = [(1, 'Arrive in Warehouse'), (2, 'Checking failures'),
     (3, 'Packaging'), (4, 'Shipping'), (5, 'Received')]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','b'])
    

final = ['ID'] + df1.sort_values('a')['b'].tolist() + ['NAME']
df['STATUS'] = pd.Categorical(df['STATUS'], categories=final, ordered=True)

df = (df.pivot(index=['ID', 'NAME'], columns='STATUS', values='DATE')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
        .sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
   ID  Arrive in Warehouse    Checking failures            Packaging  \
0   1  2023-01-01 00:00:00                  NaN  2023-02-01 00:00:00   
1   2  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00                  NaN   

              Shipping             Received NAME  
0  2023-03-01 00:00:00  2023-04-01 00:00:00  PS5  
1  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00  Fan
```

Similar idea with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - change order by `final` list (with all possible values):

```
final = ['ID'] + df1.sort_values('a')['b'].tolist() + ['NAME']

df = (df.pivot(index=['ID', 'NAME'], columns='STATUS', values='DATE')
        .rename_axis(columns=None)
        .reset_index()
        .reindex(final, axis=1))
print (df)
   ID  Arrive in Warehouse    Checking failures            Packaging  \
0   1  2023-01-01 00:00:00                  NaN  2023-02-01 00:00:00   
1   2  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00                  NaN   

              Shipping             Received NAME  
0  2023-03-01 00:00:00  2023-04-01 00:00:00  PS5  
1  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00  Fan
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a CategoricalDtype to maintain order:

```
cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['ID'] + df['STATUS'].unique().tolist() + ['NAME'], ordered=True)
out = (df.astype({'STATUS': cat})
         .pivot(index=['ID', 'NAME'], columns='STATUS', values='DATE')
         .reset_index().sort_index(axis=1).rename_axis(columns=None))
```

Output:

```
>>> out

   ID  Arrive in Warehouse            Packaging             Shipping             Received    Checking failures NAME
0   1  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-02-01 00:00:00  2023-03-01 00:00:00  2023-04-01 00:00:00                  NaN  PS5
1   2  2023-01-01 00:00:00                  NaN  2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00  Fan
```

Comment: My second solution ;)

Comment: I use `CategoricalDtype`, I don't need to use an intermediate dataframe because the order of `STATUS` is already right so `df1` is not useful here. Finally, the `pivot.reset_index.rename_axis` is a standard pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Using a simple [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`pop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) to move the NAME to the end:

```
order = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'Arrive in Warehouse'), (2, 'Checking failures'),
                      (3, 'Packaging'), (4, 'Shipping'), (5, 'Received')], 
                     columns=['index', 'STATUS'])

out = (
 df.pivot(index=['ID', 'NAME'], columns='STATUS', values='DATE')
   .reindex(columns=order.sort_values(by='index')['STATUS'])
   .reset_index()
   .assign(NAME=lambda d: d.pop('NAME'))
)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
STATUS  ID  Arrive in Warehouse    Checking failures            Packaging  \
0        1  2023-01-01 00:00:00                  NaN  2023-02-01 00:00:00   
1        2  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00                  NaN   

STATUS             Shipping             Received NAME  
0       2023-03-01 00:00:00  2023-04-01 00:00:00  PS5  
1       2023-01-03 00:00:00  2023-01-04 00:00:00  Fan
```

Comment: I think principe - sorting by reindex.

Comment: Can you be concrete?